# alternative for MultiFieldQueryParser

Tags: java, apache, lucene

I am very new to `lucene`. I want to have search over multiple field. I am doing some thing like this

```
Query q = null;
        try {
            q = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LATEST,fields,new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LATEST)).parse(strSearch);
            int hitsPerPage = 10;
            TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(hitsPerPage, true);

            searcher.search(q, collector);
            return collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;
        } catch (org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

It work fine for me but I want want to know what are alternative for  `MultiFieldQueryParser` and `StandardAnalyzer`. It shows deprecated in `lucene 4.10`.

Comment: [Remove the version argument.](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/MultiFieldQueryParser.html#MultiFieldQueryParser(org.apache.lucene.util.Version,%20java.lang.String[],%20org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to specify version(Version.LATEST) just using following constructor issue resolved for me.

MultiFieldQueryParser(String[] fields, Analyzer analyzer)